# Reading and parsing files in C

Tags: c, fopen

I'v got a file file.txt contains two columns of scientific data. 
Each row contains two values (one for column 0 and one for column 1).

10 9.5
-8 5
-8 5
-3 6.25
-9 4.75
4 8
-6 5.5
...

My task is to write some software in C to calculate the average of the column 1 and display the result.

Comment: data from the second column are ignored?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fscanf`. `fscanf` works a bit like the opposite of `printf`. You specify the kind of string you will read and to what variables those values will be assigned. `fscanf` will read each line of the file and will return the number of elements read successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE* test_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    double sum = 0;
    unsigned number_elements = 0;
    while(1){
        double first, second;
        if (fscanf(test_file, "%lf %lf", &first, &second) < 2){
            break;
        }
        ++number_elements;
        sum += second;
    }

    fclose(test_file);

    printf("Average: %f\n", sum/number_elements);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow this fscanf is Awesome! Thanks